How to set div height according to content
I need to show a set of text symbols in several rows, each one in different div element. When I try this I get the height of div is greater that height of text. I prepared example
to demonstrate this. How to change the style so that the height of div would be fit to text's height?


function showText() {
  const codePoint1 = 0x1F031;
  const codePoint2 = 0x1F032;
  const codePoint3 = 0x1F033;
  document.getElementById("div1").textContent = String.fromCodePoint(codePoint1);
  document.getElementById("div2").textContent = String.fromCodePoint(codePoint2);
  document.getElementById("div3").textContent = "abc"
  // String.fromCodePoint(codePoint3);
}
showText();
.divText {
  border: solid;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
}
<div id="div1" class="divText"></div>
<div id="div2" class="divText"></div>
<div id="div3" class="divText"></div>




I added your example in the question (reason : Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?).

If you mean that there is no space above/below the text then this is possible but not recommended. The space is their for a reason (see ascenders/descenders) to make multiline text readable and visually appealing. You can tweak the line-height but this is highly inflexible and font dependent. In addition, the space might be in the character glyph and thus impossible to remove. - EG - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ExzNaOX

If you don't set a height, the div height will be the text height. If you select the symbols, you can see that there is no space added, it's just that the symbols contain space.

@Cédric: firstly, thanks for editing my text. Secondly, if to delete "height: 50px;" in css that there will be additional space also under the text content.

@ Paulie_D: unless another solution is suggested, I'll use line-height. The problem is that different divs partially overlap. I'm adding an addEventListener on click to each div and the overlap is preventing the click zone from being detected correctly

It appears to me that the symbols you're trying to add take a lot of line-height, so you could simply modify and tweak the "line-height" property to reach the outcome you want.
to make it clear, your div is in fact fitting the height of your elements, it's just that your elements have empty gaps on top and bottom, it's not an issue of spacing, but rather the element (or symbol) itself.
A div automatically takes the height and width of their child elements, you could also set height: fit-content manually, which does the same thing, you can do this with width as well.

I did not use "line-height" in this jsfiddle example. The symbols I added to divs are just simple text such as "abc". Using of "height: fit-content" does not help.

@eug100 The third div you've added is abc, the first two are symbols such as this, you didn't use line-height yourself, but all characters have some line-height inherently, you could change that, for example use line-height: 0.5 and see the result.

@ Sajjad Ostadebrahim: thank you, I think you are right. I really use line-height now.
